# How can I join tables in Zend while using a class that inherits from Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I have a class that extends Zend_Db_Table lets call it 'Users' that uses the class 'User' (inheriting from Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract) as its rowClass. I need it this way because User has additional methods that I use.

As far as I know it is not possible to join tables inside my Users class so I use:

> $query = $db->select();
>           $query->from(...);
>           $query->joinInner(...);

instead of

> $this->select(); ...

But then of course the rows I get are not of the User class. So I would like to know how can I force my query to return User objects instead of Row objects.

Another way would be to get Zend_Db_Table to make that join in which case I would also get what I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Join in Zend Framework.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311481/how-to-use-join-in-zend-framework) and a couple others.

Comment: Once you see that answer and know something about Zend you can see the questions are very related but I still think keeping this questions has value because the keywords my questions contains was what I searched for and couldn't find so maybe someone else has the same problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting David Caunt's answer in linked duplicate:

> Because Zend_Db_Table provides row gateway functions, which don't work if you join on other  tables, you have to state that you are willing to give it up. Simply make a call to `setIntegrityCheck` and it will work:
>
> `$select->setIntegrityCheck(false);`

Comment: Works perfectly to get Zend_Db_Table to make that join.