# Select query cannot join with another table - JOIN Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:

Message: Select query cannot join with another table
This is my code:

```
<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_Seguimientos extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    protected $_name = 'Seguimientos';    
    public function buscarCaso($cod_beneficiario) {
        $consulta = $this->select()

        ->from(array('seg' => 'Seguimientos'))
        ->join(array('casos' => 'Asuntos_Estudiantiles'),
        'seg.cod_radicado = casos.codigo_radicado')
        ->where('casos.cod_beneficiario = ?', $cod_beneficiario);

        $query = $this->fetchAll($consulta)->toArray();
        return $query;
    }
}
```

I use [Zend Framework 1](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.join)
[image: error]

Comment: $select->setIntegrityCheck(false);

add this line (from the below answer)

Answer (score 25):

```
<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_Seguimientos extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    protected $_name = 'Seguimientos';

    public function buscarCaso($cod_beneficiario) {

        $consulta = $this->select()

        ->from(array('seg' => 'Seguimientos'))
        ->join(array('casos' => 'Asuntos_Estudiantiles'),
        'seg.cod_radicado = casos.codigo_radicado')
        ->where('casos.cod_beneficiario = ?', $cod_beneficiario)
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false); // ADD This Line

        $query = $this->fetchAll($consulta)->toArray();
        return $query;
    }

}
```

Solved by adding  `->setIntegrityCheck(false)`  ! =)

An explanation of why this helps is found at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440140/setintegritycheck-in-zend-selects-with-joins)